# How to force junit tests to run sequencially even for .parallel() streams?

Tags: java, junit, java-stream

I want to test a method that makes use of `.parallel()` stream, `jdk11`.

Thereby, the outcome is always different, that's why I'm trying to find a way to force junit to only allow max 1 threads for the stream execution. But how?

My idea was to wrap the execution in a `ForkJoinPool(1)` call inside the test, so that the underlying service only sees one core to execute the stream in. But it does not work:

```
@Test
public void testForceSequencial() {
    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = null;
    try {
        forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(1);
        forkJoinPool
                .submit(() -> NumberService.count())
                .join();
    } finally {
        forkJoinPool.shutdown();
    }
}

static class NumberService {
    static void count() {
        IntStream.range(1, 10)
                .sorted()
                .parallel()
                .forEach(i -> System.out.println("Number: " + i));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Number: 5
Number: 6
Number: 8
Number: 9
Number: 7
Number: 3
Number: 4
Number: 1
Number: 2
```

Comment: One core or not, your code is multi-threaded. I think you need to find a different way to verify it.

Comment: Oh okay, you mean it executes still in parallel single-core?

Comment: Yes. Even if it won't be effectively concurrent, you have code executing in parallel, so scheduling is involved and it can't be predictable.

Comment: Regardless of how many threads are involved, [`forEach` is an *unordered* operation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)). But what exactly do you want to test here?